# Segmentation fault while reading data from file

Tags: c, import-from-csv

I'm getting a segmentation fault error while parsing data from a CSV file in C Language.
I believe the error is given while reading the last line <person[i].status> as if i comment the same line the code runs perfectly.

Contents of CSV file:

```
1;A;John Mott;D;30;Z
2;B;Judy Moor;S;60;X
3;A;Kae Blanchett;S;42;y
4;B;Jair Tade;S;21;W
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Person
{
    int id;
    char key;
    char name[16];
    char rel;
    int age;
    char status;
} Person;

int main()
{
    Person person[12];

    FILE *f = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    char buffer[256];

    if (f != NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        printf("\nFile OK!\n");
        printf("Printing persons:\n");
        while (fgets(buffer, 256, f))
        {
            person[i].id = atoi(strtok(buffer, ";"));
            person[i].key = strtok(NULL, ";")[0];
            strcpy(person[i].name, strtok(NULL, ";"));
            person[i].rel = strtok(NULL, ";")[0];
            person[i].age = atoi(strtok(buffer, ";"));
            person[i].status = strtok(NULL, ";")[0]; // error: segmentation fault

            printf("id: %d\n", person[i].id);
            printf("key: %c\n", person[i].key);
            printf("name: %s\n", person[i].name);
            printf("rel: %c\n", person[i].rel);
            printf("age: %d\n", person[i].age);
            printf("status: %c\n", person[i].status);
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nFile BAD!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: *I believe the error is given while reading the last line*. Use a debugger to find out for sure. It will instantly tell you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. It can also be used the trace the code flow and examine the variable values to aid in finding the problem.

Comment: You should check the return value of every `strtok` call before attempting to use the returned pointer. It may be NULL at any point.

Comment: From the standard page: Return Value:
If a token is found, a pointer to the beginning of the token. Otherwise, a null pointer.
`A null pointer is always returned when the end of the string (i.e., a null character) is reached in the string being scanned.`  Seems like checking for NULL instead of blindly dereferencing would be a good idea.  debugging or at least printing what strtok returns is also a good idea.

Comment: Definitely its the last line. Don't know the reason though.
While debugging, the program crashes and there's no info on debug.

Comment: *there's no info on debug*. What do you mean? Do you understand what a "debugger" is? It is a tool that you run the program with that will give you lots of info on the running program, including when it crashes. If you are not aware of that tool it would be advisable to research that and learn to use it. It will save you alot of time. [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: `person[i].age = atoi(strtok(buffer, ";"));` is wrong. Apart from not checking the `strtok` value the first arg should be `NULL` to continue parsing from the previous call.

Comment: Exception has occurred.
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) on the last line

Comment: Fix the things we have told you already and I think that will solve your problem: 1. Incorrect `strotk` arg for `age`. 2. Not checking return values.

Comment: It fixed it! Thank you!
Please add the answer for my to check.

Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231392/discussion-between-zumuha-and-kaylum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have a good answer addressing your problems with `strtok()`, you may be over-complicating your code by using `strtok()` to begin with. When reading a delimited file with a fixed delimiter, reading a line-at-a-time into a sufficiently sized buffer and then separating the buffer into the needed values with `sscanf()` can provide a succinct (and in the case of your use of `atoi()` a more robust) solution.

Your fields are easily separated in this case using a carefully crafted *format-string*. For example, reading each line into a buffer (`buf` in this case) you can separate each of the lines into the needed values with:

```
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d;%c;%15[^;];%c;%d;%c",      /* convert to person/VALIDATE */
                    &person[n].id, &person[n].key, person[n].name,
                    &person[n].rel, &person[n].age, &person[n].status) == 6)
```

The conversion to `int` by `sscanf()` at least minimally validates the integer conversion. Not so with `atoi()` which will happily take `atoi ("my cow")` and fail silently returning zero without any indication things have gone wrong.

Note, in every conversion to string, you must provide a *field-width* modifier to limit the number of characters stored to one less than your array can hold (saving room for the `'\0'` nul-terminating character). Otherwise the use of the `scanf()` family `"%s"` or `"%[..]"` is no safer than using `gets()`. See [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102)

The same protection of your array bounds for `person[]` applies on your read loop. Simply keeping a count of the successful conversions and testing before the next read is all you need, e.g.

```
#define NPERSONS  12        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXNAME   16
#define MAXC    1024
...
    char buf[MAXC];                                     /* buffer to hold each line */
    size_t n = 0;                                       /* person counter/index */
    Person person[NPERSONS] = {{ .id = 0 }};            /* initialize all elements */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    ...
    while (n < NPERSONS && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* protect array, read line   */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d;%c;%15[^;];%c;%d;%c",      /* convert to person/VALIDATE */
                    &person[n].id, &person[n].key, person[n].name,
                    &person[n].rel, &person[n].age, &person[n].status) == 6)
            n++;        /* increment count on good conversion */
    }
```

As shown with the `#define`s above, don't use *MagicNumbers* in your code. (e.g. `12`, `16`). Instead declare a constant at the top of your code that provides a convenient single-location to change if your limits later need adjustment.

In the same vein, do not hardcode filenames. There is no reason you should have to re-compile your code just to read from a different file. Pass the filename as the first argument to your program (that's what `argc` and `argv` are for), or prompt the user and take the filename as input. Above, the code takes the filename as the first argument, or reads from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided (like most Unix utilities do).

Putting that altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NPERSONS  12        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXNAME   16
#define MAXC    1024

typedef struct Person {
    int id;
    char key;
    char name[MAXNAME];
    char rel;
    int age;
    char status;
} Person;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC];                                     /* buffer to hold each line */
    size_t n = 0;                                       /* person counter/index */
    Person person[NPERSONS] = {{ .id = 0 }};            /* initialize all elements */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (n < NPERSONS && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* protect array, read line   */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d;%c;%15[^;];%c;%d;%c",      /* convert to person/VALIDATE */
                    &person[n].id, &person[n].key, person[n].name,
                    &person[n].rel, &person[n].age, &person[n].status) == 6)
            n++;        /* increment count on good conversion */
    }
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)                      /* output results */
        printf ("person[%zu]  %3d  %c  %-15s  %c  %3d  %c\n", i,
                person[i].id, person[i].key, person[i].name,
                person[i].rel, person[i].age, person[i].status);
}
```

(**note:** you only need one call to `printf()` to output any contiguous block of output with conversions. If you have no conversions required, use `puts()` or `fputs()` if end-of-line control is needed)

Lastly, ***do not skimp on buffer size***. `16` seems horribly short for a `name` field (`64` is still pushing it). By using the *field-width* modifier you are protected against *Undefined Behavior* due to overwriting your array bounds (the code will simply skip the line), but you should add an `else { ... }` condition to output an error in that case. `16` is sufficient for your example data, but for general use, you would want to adjust that to a larger value.

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample input in the file named `dat/person_id-status.txt`, you could do:

```
$ ./bin/person_id-status dat/person_id-status.txt
person[0]    1  A  John Mott        D   30  Z
person[1]    2  B  Judy Moor        S   60  X
person[2]    3  A  Kae Blanchett    S   42  y
person[3]    4  B  Jair Tade        S   21  W
```

Those there the main points that struct me looking over your code. (I'm sure I've forgotten to mention one or two more) Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.